# PHP Stats Object Stored in Memory Concurrent Updates = Data Loss?

Tags: php, apc

I want to abstract stats counting on objects within my system to a single place. At the moment each object increments a counter on its row in the MySQL table i.e. `UPDATE sometable SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = ?`

In order to get a significant performance gain instead of writing this update to the DB every time the object is used, I'd like to use apc to store a singleton analytics object in memory increment counters within this object and periodically save this object back to the DB.

However am I right in understanding that if two people visit the same page and increment the stats object it's possible that one of the views could be lost if they both do `$obj->views = $obj->views + 1` because the stats object got from apc will have the same total view count, they both increment one and subsequently overwrite each other.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you act in three steps :

- fetching an entry from APC
- working on it
- pushing it back to APC

Then, yes, you might have concurrency problems.

A better solution would be to have one APC entry for each one of your counters ; and use the [**`apc_inc()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-inc.php) function to increment it.

It probably means having many entries *(one per counter)* -- but it also means that, in most sitautions *(when incrementing the counters, which is what will be done the most)*, you won't have to care about concurrency : APC will deal with that for you.

Only problem that should remain is when you'll want to :

- Fetch the value of a counter,
- Store that value to database,
- And reset the counter.

There, You might meet concurrency problems again.

Two solutions :

- Consider this will not happen again *(this operation should be quite rare, compared to the incrementation)*, and accept to loose a little bit of data
- Deal with a locking mecanism yourself :

  - Create an APC entry that says "this counter is locked"
  - Do the fetching + DB thing + reset
  - Remove the lock
  - In the meantime, if some other script wants to increment the counter, it should check if the lock-entry is there ; and if so, wait a couple milliseconds, until the lock is removed.

As a couple of sidenotes, now :

- You could do the same kind of things with memcached, the day you need several web-servers -- see [**`Memcache::increment`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/memcache.increment.php)
- In both cases, APC and memcached are **caching mecanism**, and not persistant data-stores ! Which means they can evict your data whenever they need to *(this will happen when they don't have enough memory left for new entries, or when your entries will become too old)*

For the second point, your might want to switch to another solution, that would :

- Be faster than MySQL
- Persist to disk

Comment: Indeed the example in the question will overwrite earlier changes. Besides this excellent solution (which is OK for a low number of pure counters). Another solution in Memcached (as opposed to APC) would be the ability to use [CAS tokens](http://ww.php.net/manual/en/memcached.cas.php), which can prevent you from overwriting if there has been a change to more complex variables / objects.